# JavaScript Date CET

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps-script

i am working on script which creates events in Google Calendar from data in SpreadSheet. Following code creates events 
in default calendar.

```
function myFunction() {
  cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  cal.createEvent(
      'Single day', 
      new Date("October 25, 2011 15:00:00 EST"), 
      new Date("October 25, 2011 16:00:00 EST"), 
      {}
  );
  cal.createAllDayEvent('All day', new Date("October 25, 2011"), {});
}
```

The problem is, it creates the events at wrong timing. The all day event is created OK of course

[image: Single day event with EST timezone code]
[image: All day event]

I guess i am supposed to use another timezone code, but when i use CET it creates the event in the begining of epoch

```
function myFunction() {
  cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  cal.createEvent(
      'Single day', 
      new Date("October 25, 2011 15:00:00 CET"), 
      new Date("October 25, 2011 16:00:00 CET"), 
      {}
  );
  cal.createAllDayEvent('All day', new Date("October 25, 2011"), {});
}
```

[image: Event created with CET timezone code]

And again all day event is OK, becouse i don't use any time zone code.

Format of `Date` contructor i found here http://code.google.com/intl/cs-CZ/googleapps/appsscript/class_calendar.html#createEvent

So my question is what's the correct code for Central European Time ? Better could be reference for page with these codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CET is the correct abbreviation for [Central European Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/eu/cet.html).

It sounds like you found a bug, please file it on the [Apps Script Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Best,

Anton